# Howto change all links to text in a div tag

Tags: jquery

I'd like to get rid of all links in a specific div tag with the help of jquery.

E.g from this:

```
<div id="some_div">
    <a href="whatever.html">click here</a>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="some_div">
    click here
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
var textToReplace = $("#some_div a").text();
$("#some_div").text(textToReplace);
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.4, you can use [`$.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$("#some_div a").contents().unwrap();
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/otobu/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#some_div').text($('#some_div').text());
```